# How to use glp_exact to simplex method in glpk matlab

Tags: matlab, octave, linear-programming, glpk

I am trying to solve an LP minimization problem with glpk solver in octave for large data. my constraint matrix is having `1000` or more rows. My decision variable values are fractional. I am using two phase dual simplex method. I want to use `glp_exact` in octave/matlab. Here is how my glpk looks like:

```
param.dual = 3
param.presol = 1
[xmin, fmin] = glpk (c, A, b, lb, ub, ctype, vartype, s, param)
```

I don't have any idea how to use `exact` to simplex method. Any help regarding this will be really appreciated.